# How to wire an ignition switch for boat throttle controller

Tags: electrical, wiring, boat

I have an old Bass Tracker boat.  They no longer make the throttle controller for the boat, but I need to replace the ignition switch (which is in the throttle controller).  I looked online and this product looks about the same as the ignition I have to replace:

[image]

[Gander Mountain Link](http://m.gandermountain.com/modperl/product/details.cgi?pdesc=Sierra-Switch-Ignition-Sierra-Part-MP41090&i=900274&r=view&cvsfa=2586&cvsfe=2&cvsfhu=393030323734&kpid=900274&gclid=CM_63tTMnMYCFQMbaQodjL4AIQ)

But the wires on the existing ignition don't have the same colors as this one.  How do I know what to connect to what??

Doug

Comment: What color are the ones which are in the original switch?

Comment: Also, does the new switch have the same amount of wires coming out of it the old one does? (Looking for that one-for-one thing, lol)